# Flatten an array Iterative, Recursive, and apply in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration, apply, flatten

I have a interview coming up and one of the questions I was given to prepare with was to flatten an array Iteratively, recursively, and with using apply.

I have came up with a few different solutions but they all sort of borrow properties from the other. My iterative solution uses apply, and my two recursive ones I built use some form of iteration.

Do you feel that these solutions would be accepted as they are? If not how could I improve them to match the expectations?

Recursive:

```
 var flattenArrRecursive = arr => {
  var flattened = [];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(Array.isArray(item)) {
      flattened.push(...flattenArrRecursive(item));
      //flattened.push.apply(flattened, flattenArrRecursive(item));
    } else {
      flattened.push(item);
    }
  })
  return flattened;
}
```

Iterative / apply:

```
var flattenArrIterative2 = arr => {
  var result = [];
  var todo = [arr];
  while(todo.length) {
    var current = todo.shift();
    if(Array.isArray(current)) {
      todo.unshift.apply(todo, current);
    } else {
      result.push(current);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Would you accept these as solutions for the question?

I also have this recursive function but I did not write it entirely myself and would not like to use it.

```
var flattenArrRecursive = arr =>
  //reduce runs if statement on each element, similar to forEach but removes element from original arr in the process
  arr.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flattenArrRecursive(b): b), []
  );
```

Comment: I feel this is subjective and depends on the interviewer. Personally, I would use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for flattening but that's not to say I'm correct. That's what great about programming, there are thousands of way to solve the same issue. Rather than focusing on the code itself, I recommend focusing on the _concepts_. If you can explain what the difference between iteration/recursion (also benefits/drawbacks), I feel that would be more valuable. Again, just my opinion. Best of luck.

Comment: Instead of using `apply` or spread syntax, they probably expected you to iterate the array items and push them separately. Especially in the iterative version.

Comment: Indeed, a good technical interviewer is interested not in the specific solution you come up with, but rather how you arrive at a solution.

Comment: Thank you! I have a good grasp of these concepts and can explain how they differ from each other easily, I must have been overthinking the code too much. I appreciate the responses!